# Storyboard / Swift all IBOutlets and _view are nil

Tags: swift, interface-builder

I'm working on a Swift app and running into a crazy odd problem.  I have a simple storyboard view controller setup, it has 3 `UIButtons` a `UIImageView` and a `UIView` (as a subview of the main view).

I want to programmatically add a `WKWebView` to the `UIView`.

Easy enough right?  All of the above are in the Storyboard View, declared in the custom `UIViewController` class and connected in IB.  However at run time, everything is nil.   This is a snippet of my code:

```
@IBOutlet var button1 : UIButton!;
@IBOutlet var button2 : UIButton!;
@IBOutlet var button3 : UIButton!;

@IBOutlet weak var containerForWebView: UIView!

var webView: WKWebView!

override func loadView()
{

}


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    displayWebPage()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

}

private func displayWebPage()
{

    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    webView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: containerForWebView.frame.size)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self

    containerForWebView.addSubview(webView)
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

When the code calls the `displayWebPage()` method I break on the first line.  In the debugger you can see all of the `UIViewController` properties are nil.  The IBOutlets are Nil and the _view variable of the `UIViewController` itself is nil.

I don't understand why this is happening.  Everything is pretty simple and easily connected.  I never ran into this sort of issue in Objective-C.  Any advice is appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: HomeViewController is the root view controller? Do you set root view controller in appdelegate?

Comment: is this causing a Crash ? I checked mine its also 0x0 but no issue at run time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `loadView` implementation. Do not override that method, always use `viewDidLoad` instead.

If you override `loadView` then you are responsible for creating controller's view and assigning it to `self.view`.

Comment: Holy guacamole!  This is why coding late at night when you're exhausted isn't always the best idea.  Yes that was exactly it and it totally makes sense.  By overriding that method and not calling the super method there was no view.  Taking that out fixed the issue.  Thanks!